# How to async bulk get(s) in memcached?

Tags: memcached, spymemcached

Is it possible to send a bulk gets call to memcached using spymemcached? (Note the gets to get CAS ID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a way to send bulk gets in spymemcached. In the future though all operations will most likely be sent as bulk operations under the hood. This means that you will send everything as a single operation and they will all get packaged up in spymemcached as a single bulk operation. This functionality might be available in version 3.0.

Comment: You can, however, send a bunch of async `gets` requests and then harvest the results after.  That will automatically convert the individual requests to a bulk request.

Comment: No, that doesn't work anymore. We changed it so you can only aggregate get operations together. This was in response to a ClassCastException bug. I think the fix was put in for 2.7. In the future though we will change it back to being able to do it the way Dustin is talking about (without the bug of course).

Comment: Thanks, is there an issue number I can track to watch for the change?